# Questions with the most views

Tags: bug, views

I was recently reading Glorfindel's helpful answer at [How did this question get so many views?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/how-did-this-question-get-so-many-views) and clicked on the link for "here is a list of questions with the most views on the site". That took me to a page titled ["Questions with the most views"](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1354597/questions-with-the-most-views?NumberOfHits=100), but the list seems to be broken. Does this exist anywhere else, or can it be fixed? I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are reset every week, when the data gets refreshed. You have to click the 'Run Query' button (well, not right now, since I already ran it):

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you, I saw the code (or script, or whatever it is) at the top and thought it wasn't displaying properly. That's great!

Comment: It's SQL. One of the 'problems' of Stack Exchange is that its population is heavily skewed towards programmers, thanks to [so]. We often forget things like that, our apologies!